# Custom post template

Tags: templates

Hi i want to create a wordpress template of custom post name is album. I want to show posts By grouping
$Q1 = jan,,feb,mar
$Q2 = Apr,may,jun  same for Q3 and Q4.

Now when i click on Q1 then it show posts under this. For Better explaination please check screenshot.

Q1,Q2,Q3 etc work like tabs and the content will be slide 
[image]

Comment: what have you tried? what specific problem are you having?

Comment: till i have not try anything for this

Comment: Can you guide me how can we make this dynamic. The main thing is Q1,Q2,Q3 post get according to these Quarters